# Is there any way to get appointment slots data from google calendar using Google CalendarApp script?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I was trying to import Google calendar all the appointment slots and put them in the Google Sheet using Google CalendarApp Script. But when I am fetching all the events, it returns every event except for the Appointment Slots from the calendar.

Does anybody know, how to fetch these types of things from the calendar, which is apparently not an Event ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the moment, this is not possible - you cannot retrieve appointment slots data using the Google Calendar API.

There is a feature request submitted into Google's Public Issue Tracker. To know about its status, I suggest you visit the following link: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/36757162

Comment: Please read the question again, I am asking about the CalendarApp Scripts not the Calendar API

Comment: Hello @ChiragBansal. The `CalendarApp` class in Google Apps Script uses, in fact, the calendar API underneath. Some classes do exceptionally include extra functionality that is not provided by the public APIs, but in this case I'm afraid there is no exception - you cannot obtain this data using `CalendarApp` either.